# How to spy on a class property arrow function using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, spy

How can I spy on a class property arrow function using Jest? I have the following example test case which fails with the error `Expected mock function to have been called.`:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";

class App extends Component {
  onButtonClick = () => {
    // Button click logic.
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onButtonClick} />;
  }
}

describe("when button is clicked", () => {
  it("should call onButtonClick", () => {
    const app = shallow(<App />);
    const onButtonClickSpy = jest.spyOn(app.instance(), "onButtonClick");

    const button = app.find("button");
    button.simulate("click");
    expect(onButtonClickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I can make the test pass by changing the button's `onClick` prop to `() => this.onButtonClick()` but would prefer not to change my component implementation just for the sake of tests.

Is there any way to make this test pass without changing the component implementation?

Comment: what if we replace onButtonClick with jest.fn to test whether it is been called and then separately test the onButtonClick function? If this sounds good let me know will add a solution.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta I tried `const onButtonClickSpy = jest.fn(); app.instance().onButtonClick = onButtonClickSpy;` but I still had the same failure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [this enzyme issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/365) and [this one](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/944), you have two options:

---

**Option 1: Call `wrapper.update()` after `spyOn`**

In your case, that would be:

```js
describe("when button is clicked", () => {
  it("should call onButtonClick", () => {
    const app = shallow(<App />);
    const onButtonClickSpy = jest.spyOn(app.instance(), "onButtonClick");

    // This should do the trick
    app.update();
    app.instance().forceUpdate();

    const button = app.find("button");
    button.simulate("click");
    expect(onButtonClickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

---

**Option 2: Don't use class property**

So, for you, you would have to change your component to:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
 }

  onButtonClick() {
    // Button click logic.
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onButtonClick} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work, and while Option 2 would work, the reason I'm using class properties is to avoid all the manual binding.